# Unable to run pytests in a docker container

Tags: docker, pytest

I built a docker image and tried to run pytest, I am getting the following error :
docker run docker-whale

> ============================= test session starts ==============================
>   platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.16, pytest-4.4.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
>   rootdir: /app
>   ========================= no tests ran in 0.00 seconds =========================
>   ERROR: file not found: --env preview

My dockerFile:

```
CMD ["pytest" , "--env preview" , "fe/tests/US/MyCom/MyPageTests/" , "-m preview"]
```

Is this happening due to conflict between docker "env" variable and my pytest "env" environment variable? If so, what is the work-around?

The same command works fine if I ssh into the docker container and run it.

Answer (score 1):

The form of CMD you're using accepts a list of arguments, and passes them exactly as given.

You've combined `--env` and `preview` into a single argument `--env preview` which pytest does not understand.

Split them out like this:

```
CMD ["pytest", "--env", "preview" , "fe/tests/US/MyCom/MyPageTests/", "-m",  "preview"]
```

Normly, if you enter this command into a shell:

```
pytest --env preview fe/tests/US/MyCom/MyPageTests/ -m preview
```

The shell will split the command line on spaces, and provide each one in an element in argv.

But with CMD, there is no shell creating an argument list. There is only docker and it's doing exactly what you tell it.